# How to prevent user from taking screenshot of MPMovieplayerController contents?

Tags: avplayer, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

I've just used `HBONow` and found that when I want to take screenshot of the movie(just like GOT),the content of the HBONow player will become black. then I know that this is the method of prevent user from share contents.

The question is,I've used MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayerViewController to play my own contents, how can I do the same thing as HBO and prevent user from taking screenshots?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After search, I've found what they use for content protecting

see this[reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6h1nkc/how_are_apps_like_netflix_hbo_go_blocking_screen/)

and

[FPS official document](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/)

Comment: You are right. it's because stream is protected. Also protected streams are not visible  in iOS/tvOS Simulator